# Find the gradient vector of $f(x,y) = (4+x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ at the point $(2, 1)$.

Tags: calculus

In this question there is no mention of a direction to use, how would I go about answering the question regardless?

Comment: Usually, when talking about the gradient, we don't talk about the "gradient in a given direction". The gradient operation itself chooses the direction for you.

Comment: I think you confused the gradient vector with the directional derivative.

Comment: @player3236 Indeed I have, thank you

Answer (score 1):

So the gradient is defined as

$$\nabla f(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{df}{dx} \\ \frac{df}{dy}\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, after calculations

$$\nabla f(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{x}{\sqrt{4+x^2+y^2}} \\ \frac{y}{\sqrt{4+x^2+y^2}}\end{pmatrix}$$

And after specializing the variables

$$\nabla f(2,1) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3}\end{pmatrix}$$